# Checking if a number only has certain digits, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an assignment where I have to multiply two numbers together and see if that number exclusively contains 5's and 2's. Here is what I have so far:

```
a = int(input('number '))
b = int(input('another number '))
c = a*b
```

Comment: Perhaps consider converting your result to string as the next step … from there, think of a way to check the individual digits in that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution:

```
set(str(c)) == {'2', '5'}
```

A `set` ignores order and removes duplicates, so this will return true as long as there are only `'2'` and `'5'` characters in the string representation of `c`, no matter their order or frequency.

Comment: Consider explaining how your solution works

Comment: @Educorreia Fair point, I have edited the post now.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to `str` by `c_as_str = str(c)` and then just check if `5 in c_as_str` or/and `2 in c_as_str`.

if it must contain both 2 and 5:

`print(5 in c_as_str and 2 in c_as_str)`

if it must contain either:

`print(5 in c_as_str or 2 in c_as_str)`

But if you want it to be "better" you can write it this way:

if both:
`print(all(x in c_as_str for x in (5,2)))`

if either:
`print(any(x in c_as_str for x in (5,2)))`

if it must contain only 2 and 5 then `set(c_as_str) == {2,5}`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate by the number's digits by converting the number into a string and iterate over its characters.

```
only_five_and_twos = True

for i in str(c):
    if i not in ("2", "5"):
        only_five_and_twos = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to solve that in many ways. You can parse the int to string and check by 2 and 5 chars or you can solve with math:

```
a = int(input('number '))
b = int(input('another number '))
c = a*b

has2 = False
has5 = False
hasOther = False

while (c != 0):
  has2 = c%10 == 2 or has2
  has5 = c%10 == 5 or has5
  hasOther = (c%10 != 2 and c%10 != 5) or hasOther
  c //= 10

if has2 and has5 and not hasOther:
  print('the number has exclusively 2 and 5')
```